# How to change the font color of a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change the font color of div using javascript .I tried a lot of combination which were avalible on internet .Here is my html code

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo3").style.backgroundColor="blue";
```

```html
<p id="demo3">test</p>
```

Comment: `style.color` is for the font color.

Comment: Just use `color` instead of `backgroundColor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML :

```
<p id="demo3">
   Test
</p>
```

JavaScript :

```
document.getElementById("demo3").style.color = "blue"; //or #ffffff
```

JavaScript Method 2 :

```
var x = document.getElementById('demo3');
x.style.color = '#ffffff';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `color` style property to change font color.

```js
document.getElementById("demo3").style.color = "red";
```

```html
<p id="demo3">test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is setting background color of the div.

Try changing to `color` instead of `backgroundColor`

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo3").style.color="blue";
```

```html
<p id="demo3">test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :

```
document.getElementById("ElementID").style.color = "YourColor";

<p id="ElementID">test</p>
```